# Why aren't my .NETCore tag helpers working for my HTML button?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a button and I trigger an action in my controller via the button. The button has tag helpers for the controller, route id, and action (see below):

(Line-breaks inserted for readability)

```
<div class="input-group-append">
    <button
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
        type="button"
        asp-controller="Home"
        asp-route-Id="@Model.Project.Id"
        asp-action="UploadDocument"
        id="uploadDocument"
    >
        Upload
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the `IActionResult` in the controller:

```
        //POST - Upload document
        [HttpPost("~/Home/UploadDocument")]
        public IActionResult UploadDocument(int id, IFormFile files)
        {
             //Get and upload file
            if (files != null)
            {
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    //Getting FileName
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                    //Getting file Extension
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    // concatenating  FileName + FileExtension
                    //var newFileName = String.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), fileExtension);                   

                    var objfiles = new Document()
                    {
                        Id = 0,
                        Name = fileName,
                        FileType = fileExtension,
                        ProjectId = id
                    };

                    using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        files.CopyTo(target);
                        objfiles.DataFiles = target.ToArray();
                    }

                    _db.Files.Add(objfiles);

                }
            }

            _db.SaveChanges();
            return View(Update(id));
        }
```

I put a breakpoint on the first line of code in `UploadDocment` and clicked the button. Nothing happened. The breakpoint never got hit. I'm not sure why this isn't working. I have:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

... in my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file and the tag helpers work on other buttons.

Answer (score 2):

- The `asp-action...` tag-helpers are for use on `<a>` and `<form>` elements, not `<button>`.
- Additionally, another part of the problem is the `type="button"` on your `<button>`.

  - `type="button"`  means that the button, when clicked, **does nothing**.
- So, to correct things:

  - Change your `<button>` to `type="submit"` to submit the parent `<form>` element.
  - And move the `asp-action=""` and `asp-controller=""` helpers to your `<form>`.

Comment: This button should just delete the document without submitting the form. I think I am going to have to use an ajax call to delete the document without submitting the form.

Comment: @NerdyDriod What's wrong with submitting the form?

Comment: The customer wants documents to be uploaded without having to submit the form. They think it is easier on their users to just hit a button to add a document to an existing entry instead of hitting "Update" (which submits the form). It's a ridiculous requirement but no one listens to the developer....

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `<button>` inside `<form method="post"></form>`.

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-route-Id="@Model.Project.Id"
            asp-action="UploadDocument"
            id="uploadDocument">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Generated html:
[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: This button should just delete the document without submitting the form. I think I am going to have to use an ajax call to delete the document without submitting the form.